# Procedure of uk visa appointment

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

Do I have to pay fee first or take a appointment First for uk visa? if I am applying from Pakistan.

Comment: Pay a fee to who? Make an appointment with who? Watch out for scammers trying to 'help' you.

Comment: Unless you're using a 3rd party service to handle the application for you, you'd typically pay it directly to HM government, either on being billed by them or on site when handling the application.

Comment: Just follow the instructions in the official application system.

Answer (score 2):

First you pay the application fee when you submit your application online. After payment of that fee you will be linked to a website where you can book your Biometric appointment and you have to pay fee for that appointment separately on that step.

1. Application Fee
2. Biometric Appointment Fee
3. (Optional) Fee for any value added services you buy from the visa application center. These value added services are not compulsory and your application is equally valid without them.